# C# use template type in foreign class

Tags: c#, class, templates

Is it possible to use a Template from a specific class in another class?

Example:

```
class DBObject<DataType>
{
    private string _name;
    private DataType _value;

    public DBObject()
    {
        _name = String.Empty;
    }

    public DBObject(string name)
    {
        this._name = name;
    }

    public DataType GetValue
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }
}
```

`DataType` is the Template I'm using in the class `DBObject`

My `TestTbl` Class contains the `DBObject<DataType>` elements.

```
class TestTbl : DBTableObjects 
{
    public DBObject<int> _id;
    DBObject<string> _name;
    DBObject<string> _address;

    TestTbl()
    {
        AddDBTableObject(_id = new DBObject<int>("id"));
    }
}
```

The `AddDBTableObject` function adds the element to a `List` in the `DBTableObjects` Class.

```
class DBTableObjects
{
    List<DBObject> ls;

    public DBTableObjects()
    {
        ls = new List<DBObject>();
    }

    protected void AddDBTableObject(DBObject obj)
    {
        ls.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

Problem: The `List<DBObject>` requires also a templatetype for the `DBObject` instance. How can I use the `DataType` from the `DBObject` Class here?

Comment: Why not use DBTableObjects<DataType> ?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in `List<DBObject> ls;` It needs to be generic:

```
class DBTableObjects
{
    List<DBObject<int>> ls;

    public DBTableObjects()
    {
        ls = new List<DBObject<int>>();
    }

    protected void AddDBTableObject(DBObject<int> obj)
    {
        ls.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking, though I was going to use generic definitions, eg `<T>`

Comment: `TestTbl<DataType>` is equivelant to `TestTbl<T>`. It is just a naming, the constraints are done by using `where  DataType : struct` for example

Comment: `DBObject<DataType> _name;` and `DBObject<DataType> _id;` have the same type or am I mistaking? Because if so than that’s a problem. I need different types for different variables.